Segmentar nombres para que cada uno tenga una fecha diferente
Tengo esta tabla llamada eventos, que tiene nombre y esta puede tener la información de esta forma
nombre Pedro:Jaime delimitados con : y tiene una columna de fecha, 12/08/2024, el código hace parte de un calendario por lo que se puede asignar varias fechas, la idea del código es que por cada nombre que tenga genere nombre - fecha x cantidad de veces tal que así:
pedro 12/08/2024
Jaime 12/08/2024
hay casos en los que por ejemplo le pongo una semana asignada por lo que el resultado debería darme
pedro x cantidad de días, jaime x cantidad de días

Originalmente la tengo así:

¿Cómo podría hacer para integrar este código dentro de un loop y que el mismo pueda generarme una nueva columna que albergue la información nueva?
Código:
SELECT
    TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(nombre_recurso, '[^:]+', 1, columna_segmento.nivel)) AS valor_separado,  
    start_date + columna_fecha.nivel - 1 AS fecha
FROM
    evento
JOIN (
    SELECT LEVEL AS nivel
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (
        SELECT MAX(LENGTH(nombre_recurso) - LENGTH(REPLACE(nombre_recurso, ':', '')) + 1)
        FROM evento
        WHERE ID = 721
    )
) columna_segmento ON 1 = 1
JOIN (
    SELECT LEVEL AS nivel
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (
        SELECT end_date - start_date + 1
        FROM evento
        WHERE ID = 721
    )
) columna_fecha ON 1 = 1
WHERE
    ID = 721
ORDER BY fecha, valor_separado;


Podrías compartir las tablas que tienes en vez de imágenes ya que en dispositivos móviles no se ven bien.

Puedes utilizar apex_string.split o apex_string.split_numbers

Referencia: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aeapi/SPLIT_NUMBERS-Function.html#GUID-729E046F-4E95-45DF-8B9F-5FBEA0C08DE5
Ejemplo:
Tabla sample_apex_split_v:



